# how to convert large image PDF file to PNG?

Tags: pdf, converters

I have a large single-page PDF (about 700KB) that was automatically generated by the [Trace2UML](http://trace2uml.tigris.org/) tool. This provides the means to generate a UML interaction diagram from the trace logs obtained while running an application. It has options to export the diagram to PDF and PNG file formats; however, due to the large image size, the PNG export fails, whereas the PDF export succeeds. So I have been looking for a way to conert this large file from PDF to PNG format.

I've googled this for for a couple of hours this morning. There are lots of programs and on-line services to do it, but none of them work with my file. When I load the file into PDF-XChange Viewer, it indicates that the image size is 136 x 11186 cm. So, definitely huge! Is there any way to convert this file?

Comment: Without knowing what you tried, and without being able to test because of lack of a file with that kind of dimensions, it is difficult to make a meaningful suggestion. Let alone try things out in their favorite `pdf2png` utility. Can you share the file somewhere and make a list of softwares you have tried in vain.

Comment: That's a big file :) Can you make an example available so we can test?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't upload the file to Dropbox from work. Here's the link to the PDF file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/09gk3ur0ncmt12o/SequenceDiagram.pdf
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, the Preview could convert pdf to png (just open pdf and save as png), not sure if it works for large file though.